# How to comment out first occurrence of line after an original matching line bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a bash script for a homework assignment that finds the first occurrence of this line: "cin >>n;" after int main() in a c++ file and comments it out.

The problem is that "cin >> n" may or may not exist inside of main, and main can have any size of lines so I have to search for main() and then search again from main for "cin >> n;" after finding main. I assume sed can be used for this but I only know how to search for one thing at a time.

Here's and example of an input file:

```
#include <studio.h>
void hi()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n; //I dont want to be commented out
  prinf("hi");
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  bool foo = false;
  cin >> n; //I want to be commented out
  if(!foo){
    cin >> n; //I dont want to be commented out
  }  
}

void supp(){
  cin >> n; //I dont want to be commented out
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a solution but you changed the question.

Comment: Apologies, the assignment was ambiguous and after some discussion with my teacher I realized I had interpreted it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is correctly indented as shown above and is called `prog.c`, you can issue:

```sh
sed '/^int main/,$s|^  \( *cin >>.*\)|//&\n§§|' prog.c |
sed '/^§§/,$s|//\( *cin >> n\)|  \1|' |
sed '/^§§/d'
```

The idea is to comment out all the lines, between `int main()` and the end of the file, containing `cin >> n` and adding a line containing `§§` (could be something else) just after each matched line.

The second step is to remove from the comments all the lines having `cin >> n` after the first occurence of `§§` until the end of the `main()` function.

Once this is done, all the lines containing `§§` must be removed.

**Edit:**

I found a much easier solution, after thinking a lot:

```sh
sed '/^int main/,/^ *cin >> n/s|^  \( *cin >>.*\)|//\1|' prog.c
```

The idea behind this second solution is to comment out all the lines having `cin >> n` from the line where `int main()` stays, up to the line with the first occurrence of `cin >> n`. As simple as that. Sorry that I didn't see this before.

**Demo**

This is the output of both solutions above:

```c
#include <studio.h>
void hi()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n; //I dont want to be commented out
  prinf("hi");
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  bool foo = false;
//  cin >> n; //I want to be commented out
  if(!foo){
      cin >> n; //I dont want to be commented out
  }  
}

void supp(){
  cin >> n; //I dont want to be commented out
}
```

Comment: How would I remove the functionality of it only being in between main? It doesn't necessarily have to be inside of main it just has to match the first one after main, meaning that it could be outside of the function.

Comment: If the first occurence of `cin >>> n` to be commented out can also take place after `main()`, then the range of addresses ending on `/^}/` can be changed into `$`, which means ending on the last line (change at two places). I will edit my answer taking this element into account.

Comment: Thinking better about this problem, I found a much better solution: see my edit.